# HTTP Request will not go through the controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I have created a simple Maven project with a simple controller class which will only show the server time, but it never goes through the controller, would be glad for any help.

*My Controller class:*

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class Test
{
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StudentsController.class);


@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    logger.info("Welcome home! the client locale is "+ locale.toString());

    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

    model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );
    System.out.println(formattedDate);

    return "index";
}

}
```

web.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
 </web-a
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"          
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

      <!-- not strictly necessary for this example, but still useful, see       
       http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference 
       /html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-controller for more information -->
       <context:component-scan base-package="test" />
       <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>


       <!-- the mvc resources tag does the magic -->
      <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

        <!-- also add the following beans to get rid of some exceptions -->
       <bean        
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
       <bean
         class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        </bean>

     <!-- JSTL resolver -->
      <bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
     <property name="viewClass"
     value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
       <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
       <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
      </bean>
```

index.jsp

```
  <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
  <html>
<head>
    <title>Spring RESTful Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Your WebApplication is up and running....</p>

    <div>
    Server Time is:

<div>
${serverTime} 

</div>  
    </div>
</body>
  </html>
```

and when I run it on Tomcat server the output is:

```
Your WebApplication is up and running....
 Server Time is:
 ${serverTime}
```

Please any help?

Comment: I don't see why it should. I'd create some utility class with `getServerTime()` method, import it in JSP and as it for time.

Comment: Can you post the error/stacktrace that you get?

Comment: There is no any error out put, it shows the index page as I mentioned above but dosen't show the time and even a System.out.println("hello"); , can't be printed. It never gos throw the controller class.

Comment: What request URL did you try in your browser?

Comment: The url should be /index/index

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be with Tomcat - can you see if you have a web.xml file in tomcat.home\conf folder, with entries along these lines:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    ....


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is the one which interprets the jsp.

Just to debug, one more thing that I would try is to put these entries explicitly in your applications web.xml file also.

Update: @user1067665 after trying out a little more based on your comments, it definitely doesn't sound like a Tomcat issue, it is more an application configuration issue. I think what will fix it is to replace your definition of AnnotationHandlerAdapter and the DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping with `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`, can you please try this and see if works out

Comment: Yes I've checked it and these lines are in the web.xml in the config folder. I believe the problem is Tomcat but don't know where and what. I tried with these lines in the web.xml too but get the same result.

Comment: Okay, can I request you to try one more thing - can you use the tomcat plugin in maven to start up your application and see if you the jsp is still not getting interpreted - this is how you add a tomcat plugin:  <plugin><groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId><artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId><version>1.0</version></plugin> and start it up using mvn tomcat:run

Comment: Yes tomcat starts up and running.

Comment: Cool, and do you still get back the un-interpreted jsp or a proper page when you start up tomcat this way through maven and access your page - this is just to find again whether this is an application issue or Tomcat issue

Comment: ok but still have the same problem and no nay out put by the controller.

Comment: Based on your comments, it is definitely not a Tomcat issue, I have tried in my machine also and what worked for me was replacing your definition of AnnotationHandlerAdapter and DefaultRequestMapping..with mvc:annotation-driven, can you please try this and see if it works out. I have updated my answer also

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Please can you post the code?

Comment: Sure, delete the lines in your spring-servlet.xml file, which define these two beans - org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter, org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping and replace it with `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`

Comment: I have put a temporary project in github at - git@github.com:bijukunjummen/mvc-test.git, try it out by running mvn tomcat:run and accessing your page at http://localhost:8080/mvc-test, it should work as expected.

Comment: It's working now and i don't know how I can tanks you. I'm greatfully. And Tanks tanks and so many tanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

You've also double mapped your request ... the path will be /index/index

Remove the "value" parameter from the method level annotation, you can leave the "method" parameter.

Comment: With our without value parameter I'll get the same out put. So it's not about the value parameter. I have tried everything without any result.